# How to use node fluent-ffmpeg tp get video dimensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I am using fluent-ffmpeg and i need to return width and height for the video

currently I am using on win the following code but with no result (data = undefined).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
 ffmpeg('C:\Projects\test.mp4')
   .ffprobe(0, function(err, data) {
     console.log('file1 metadata:');
     console.dir(data);
     console.log(err);
   });
```

Comment: one problem is with the \ characters ... in node you can use / instead (or \\ )

Comment: ok, using \\ works, please add it as answer I will be glad to accept it thanks